# Application behaving differently in heroku vs localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

In my application I'm making events. When I destroy them, a flash appears once the user is redirected to the events#index page. Here is the destroy action:

```
def destroy
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        @event.destroy
        redirect_to events_path
        flash[:notice] = 'Event destroyed!'
    end
```

This works fine on localhost. However, once the app has been pushed to Heroku, it does not function. When clicked the user is taken to the show page for the specific event. Here is the link_to for the button as well. Any clues as to why this is?

```
<button>
    <%=link_to('Destroy Event', event, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the '#{event.name}' event?"}) %>
</button>
```

Comment: Check the heroku server logs.... something tells me you are performing a GET not a DELETE (hence why you are being routed to the show action)  `heroku logs --tail` to see your (constantly updating) server logs

Comment: Not seeing any updates in the logs within console when I hit the destroy button. Any ideas on why this may be happening if this is the case?

Comment: Weird that it would be working on localhost but not heroku.

Comment: You don't see *any* update in the heroku logs when you click on the delete link?

Comment: Nothing. The logs aren't updating when I do anything in the heroku app

Comment: Why are you putting a `link_to` inside a `<button>`? That really doesn't make much sense and it won't produce valid HTML since a [`<button>` cannot contain interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/forms.html#the-button-element).

Comment: Fair enough. That's easy enough to deal with. This other issue is keeping me stumped.